# Implement Actionbar in Android Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

How to implement the ActionBar in android honeycomb? How to customize the action bar? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In the future, use Google to research the basic things you need to do, then come here if you have a specific programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the following resource to know more about implementing the action bar-

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout."id", null);
    // lay.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
    // android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    // android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    //Not wrking
    actionBar.setCustomView(view);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```